# GoogleMobileAdsSDK 7.68 conflicts with Appodeal Unity SDK (v2.10.7)

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, cocoapods, appodeal, google-mobile-ads

I have Google Admob and Appodeal sdk integrated in my unity app. They did not have conflicts when the version of Admob SDK for unity stays at 5.3.0.

After I updated Admob SDK to v5.4.0 which depends GoogleMobileAdsSDK v7.68 today, I got the following error messages when I performed iOS build of my app:

=====================

```
iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and succeeded. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions.

pod install output:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK":
  In Podfile:
    APDGoogleAdMobAdapter (= 2.7.5.1) was resolved to 2.7.5.1, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.66.0)

    Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.68)


/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
    [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [0m



pod repo update output:

Updating spec repo `cocoapods`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/daone/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods fetch origin --progress
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/daone/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/daone/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at ffd0e56acc8e [Add] TestFido 18.10.0


/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
    [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [0m
  remote: Enumerating objects: 104, done.        
  remote: Counting objects:   0% (1/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   1% (2/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   2% (3/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   3% (4/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   4% (5/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   5% (6/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   6% (7/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   7% (8/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   8% (9/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:   9% (10/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  10% (11/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  11% (12/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  12% (13/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  13% (14/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  14% (15/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  15% (16/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  16% (17/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  17% (18/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  18% (19/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  19% (20/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  20% (21/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  21% (22/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  22% (23/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  23% (24/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  24% (25/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  25% (26/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  26% (28/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  27% (29/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  28% (30/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  29% (31/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  30% (32/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  31% (33/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  32% (34/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  33% (35/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  34% (36/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  35% (37/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  36% (38/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  37% (39/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  38% (40/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  39% (41/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  40% (42/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  41% (43/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  42% (44/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  43% (45/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  44% (46/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  45% (47/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  46% (48/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  47% (49/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  48% (50/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  49% (51/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  50% (52/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  51% (54/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  52% (55/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  53% (56/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  54% (57/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  55% (58/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  56% (59/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  57% (60/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  58% (61/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  59% (62/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  60% (63/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  61% (64/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  62% (65/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  63% (66/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  64% (67/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  65% (68/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  66% (69/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  67% (70/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  68% (71/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  69% (72/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  70% (73/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  71% (74/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  72% (75/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  73% (76/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  74% (77/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  75% (78/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  76% (80/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  77% (81/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  78% (82/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  79% (83/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  80% (84/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  81% (85/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  82% (86/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  83% (87/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  84% (88/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  85% (89/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  86% (90/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  87% (91/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  88% (92/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  89% (93/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  90% (94/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  91% (95/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  92% (96/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  93% (97/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  94% (98/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  95% (99/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  96% (100/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  97% (101/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  98% (102/104)        
  remote: Counting objects:  99% (103/104)        
  remote: Counting objects: 100% (104/104)        
  remote: Counting objects: 100% (104/104), done.        
  remote: Compressing objects:   1% (1/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   3% (2/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   4% (3/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   6% (4/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   8% (5/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   9% (6/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  11% (7/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  13% (8/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  14% (9/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  16% (10/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  18% (11/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  19% (12/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  21% (13/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  22% (14/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  24% (15/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  26% (16/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  27% (17/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  29% (18/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  31% (19/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  32% (20/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  34% (21/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  36% (22/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  37% (23/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  39% (24/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  40% (25/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  42% (26/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  44% (27/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  45% (28/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  47% (29/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  49% (30/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  50% (31/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  52% (32/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  54% (33/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  55% (34/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  57% (35/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  59% (36/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  60% (37/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  62% (38/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  63% (39/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  65% (40/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  67% (41/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  68% (42/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  70% (43/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  72% (44/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  73% (45/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  75% (46/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  77% (47/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  78% (48/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  80% (49/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  81% (50/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  83% (51/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  85% (52/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  86% (53/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  88% (54/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  90% (55/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  91% (56/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  93% (57/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  95% (58/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  96% (59/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  98% (60/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (61/61)        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (61/61), done.        
  remote: Total 72 (delta 47), reused 9 (delta 6), pack-reused 0        
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     09edb6a2e79f..ffd0e56acc8e  master     -> origin/master

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.TYKRiAmuIY/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
Google.IOSResolver:Log(String, Boolean, LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.h5EFniVWKe/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/IOSResolver/src/IOSResolver.cs:1032)
Google.IOSResolver:OnPostProcessInstallPods(BuildTarget, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.h5EFniVWKe/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/IOSResolver/src/IOSResolver.cs:2357)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

======================

Then I have tried several solutions searched on the net, including reinstalling cocoapods, removing pod repos and installing, etc. but still not solved this problem.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the APDGoogleAdMobAdapter podspec requires 7.66.x explicitly, you would need an updated version of APDGoogleAdMobAdapter that is compatible with 7.68.